# spring security authentication state check

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, intellij-idea, spring-security

i have not casual issue with the Spring MVC+Spring security.

There was emergency electricity switch-off, and as i worked with intellij IDEA on my proj, some random opened files was lost.

I recover everything, but now having a really strange issue
This is how i check authentication state on my index.jsp page

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<sec:authorize access="hasAnyAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_USER')" var="isAuthenticated"/>


    ${isAuthenticated}

                        <c:choose>
                            <c:when test="${isAuthenticated}">
                             **do smth**
                            </c:when>
                            <c:otherwise>
                             **do smth**
                            </c:otherwise>
                        </c:choose>
```

So, the **problem is:**
After successful login, i redirected to user page, i can use 'SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName()'
username from context, etc, everything is ok.
But for some reason i can't receive an authentication state,

```
${isAuthenticated}
```

**always have 'false' value.**
What should i look for? i don't get any errors.
Authenticated use have role Admin/user.

Comment: Debug `SecurityExpressionRoot` class. It uses role prefix by default. Idk how is your roles is defined but that may help you.

Comment: check where you defined roles, Also you may need to check if you have any custom authentication filters while accessing your page where you may be losing/granting authorities.